# Import Maven project to Eclipse getting error

Tags: eclipse, maven, nullpointerexception

[image: NullPointerException]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.isContained(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:470)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.isNonOverlappingResourceDescriptor(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:461)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.addResourceDirs(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:422)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.addProjectSourceFolders(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.internal.AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.configure(AbstractJavaProjectConfigurator.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:120)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.configureNewMavenProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$1.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:168)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$1.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1355)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.importProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.ImportMavenProjectsJob$1.doCreateMavenProjects(ImportMavenProjectsJob.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.run(AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.ImportMavenProjectsJob.runInWorkspace(ImportMavenProjectsJob.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

I tried mvn eclipse:eclipse and then import to Eclipse (import existing maven project) but it still throws NullPointerException

Thanks

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This question is totally different from the one you mention and where is your full stack trace? Can plz you clarify more

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a bug in m2e.  Your project likely includes references to external resources.  In my case, it was resources in the parent project:

```
  <resource>
    <directory>..</directory>
    <includes>
      <include>LICENSE</include>
      <include>NOTICE</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>
```

Changing the directory specification from .. to ${project.parent.basedir} got rid of the exceptions for me.

Comment: Seems like m2e is aware of this property, but Maven itself isn't: `[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\mypath\${project.parent.basedir}\folder`

Answer (score 1):

I was using Eclipse MARS/M2E 1.6.2/JDK 1.8u66 when I ran into this problem. Downgrade M2E 1.5.2 solve the issue for me, if you don't mind using an older M2E.

Just use the following link when installing software.
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.5/1.5.2.20150413-2215

Comment: Alternatively use m2e 1.7 from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.7/